# Evince hide all comments

Tags: pdf, evince, okular, foxitreader

I am trying to view a PDF created by AutoCAD LT; for some reason it shows with a "comment box" around all of the text elements.

I have a PDF with hundreds of little boxes that cannot be moved or hidden; if I use Foxit I am able to manually hide all comments each time I open a PDF; but I can't make this the default behavior and Foxit is slow.

I tried Okular but I can't find an option to hide comments like in Foxit.

Evince lets me disable the various layers to only show specific things; but even with all layers turned off the comment boxes are still there. Below are some screenshots of the issue.

Any help on this would be great; foxit is a work around for now but it is slow and I would rather not use it.

[image: All Layers OFF]
Evince all layers OFF

[image: All Layers ON]
Evince all layers ON

[image: Foxit with "hide all comments" selected]

Foxit with "hide all comments" selected

Comment: Could you upload or link to a small pdf file somewhere that illustrates your issue?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cbURk91_UGX23doZGAv_gQ6zpLv2yVhy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Reply from Foxit tech support; we cannot make "hide all comments" the default option...so that is annoying.